# Is there a way to call a Javascript function when a certain cookie has been dropped?

Tags: javascript, cookies

In this case, the cookie is _ric ghostery tracking cookie. We need for the user to give consent before dropping other non-essential cookies, the _ric cookie is the one that gets dropped when the user gives consent. So a sort of a cookie listener, except for cookie dropping

Comment: Call the function in the code that "drops" the cookie (otherwise known as deleting).

Comment: No event is generated when a cookie is removed (or added, for that matter), if that's what you're asking.

Comment: the function that drops the cookie is 3rd party code which we dont have access too unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question, but simply check if the cookie exists whenever you need to do that:

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf("_ric") < 0) {
  alert("cookie _ric doesn't exist");
  // do your thing...  
}
```